# JQuery Mobile Listview Disappearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am creating a JQuery Mobile web-app, and am experiencing a problem.

When then user clicks on an element in a Listview, a new page is loaded. However, when the user clicks the button, the elements in the Listview do not show.

The list elements are dynamically added, then enhanced with`$("#landmarksList").listview().listview("refresh");`

Here is a link to a page illustrating the problem:
http://jakeserver.com/Apps/BostonLandmarks/B6/landmarks.html

Any ideas about what might be causing this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: In you case page event is not loading after you return back from second page .. if is pagecreate change it to pageshow...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did not specify an event. I just put the first page that I wanted to show the one closest to the top of the HTML Page. Should I specify one? If so, where?

Comment: Could you please upload your jquery code for this particular page ...

Comment: Here is my JS file that dynamically loads the elements and pages: http://jakeserver.com/Apps/BostonLandmarks/B6/js/landmarks.js

Answer (score 0):

In JQM , DOM element are handled in differently .For example, try using `$(document).on('pageinit','#youpage'`.. instead of `$(document).ready` ....[ref](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/api/events.html).try
**Landmarks Page**

```
$(docuemnt).on('pageshow','#landmarks',function(){
   // load the landmark content dynamically here
   createListRow();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated the web server with the new event model, and it still shows up blank when I hit the back button. Any ideas?

Comment: Where you calling assembleRow function ?...and cut and paste the pageshow  event code outside that assembleRow function and try... It will work surely

Comment: I have moved the pageshow event code outside the function, and it is still having the same problem. I have found something that may help, when the .ui-overlay-a background-color is commented out, the rows are visible, however each one is doubled and they are not clickable. Do you know why the rows are under the background layer?

Comment: I figured out why multiple rows were showing (it was an accidental += in the assembleRows function). However, I still have not figured out why the rows are below the ui-overlay.